# Efficient way to insert 1000 rows to MySQL with PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have to insert 1000 rows of data per time into MySQL. At the moment, I use PDO and for-loop to insert row by row to database. Is there any more efficient way to achieve better performance? Because I have to set max_execution_time to 5 minutes.

```
function save()
{
            return $query = $this->insert("
                INSERT INTO gadata (landing_page, page_title, page_views, visits, visitors, bounce_rate, pageviews_per_visit, time_on_page, avg_time_on_page, day, month, year, hour)
                VALUES (:landing_page, :page_title, :page_views, :visits, :visitors, :bounce_rate, :pageviews_per_visit, :time_on_page, :avg_time_on_page, :day, :month, :year, :hour)", $this->data);
}
```

And

```
protected function insert($sql, array $data) {
    $q = $this->_db_handler->prepare($sql);

    foreach ($data as $k => $v)
    {
       $q->bindValue(':' . $k, $v);
    }

    $q->execute();
}
```

Comment: does the data have to be inserted via the php application? can you maybe upload the data (ie a CSV file) and use mysql's native `load data infile` ?

Comment: 1000 rows is a lot is that compulsory ?

Comment: Yes, I have to get data from other web service and insert to mysql through php code daily through cronjob.

Comment: Have you tried bulk inserting? I.e. `INSERT INTO x (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3), (4,5,6), (7,8,9), ...`?

Answer (score 2):

It is not PDO nor the way you are inserting makes insert so delayed, but **innodb** engine. So you have 3 choices:

1. Wrap all inserts into transaction.
2. using root privileges, set `innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit` variable to 2, to make innodb use a filecache for writes - it will make your inserts blazingly fast.
3. Run all the inserts in one query as suggested by Manu

Comment: Thank you, I will try wrap all insert into transaction :)

Comment: You will want to mention, that `innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit` makes InnoDB non-ACID compliant (removing the D for the last writes)

Answer (score 1):

Might not be the best solution, But you can try constructing a query string like `INSERT INTO [table] VALUES (r1c1,r1c2,r1c3),(r2c1,r2c2,r2c3) ...` and execute one `mysql_query` (or say one query for few hundred rows), you might even verify data programatically while constructing the sql query if it is not from a trusted source.

Comment: If fast is key, then bulk inserts like this are better than separate statements. Disadvantage is that you will have to do escaping of values yourself, but it certainly is faster.

Comment: Why not to use prepared statements for this query as well? It's messy but apparently feasible.

Answer (score 1):

Parameterized queries by definition trade execution safety against reduced flexibility on the count of data items.

You have at least 2 possibilities to mitigate:

- Build up the SQL, then execute it at once:

Something like:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO gadata (landing_page, page_title, page_views, visits, visitors, bounce_rate, pageviews_per_visit, time_on_page, avg_time_on_page, day, month, year, hour) VALUES ";
foreach ($all_data_rows as $data) {
  if ($i==0) $value=""; else $value=",";
  $sql.=$value."(:landing_page$i, :page_title$i, :page_views$i, :visits$i, :visitors$i, :bounce_rate$i, :pageviews_per_visit$i, :time_on_page$i, :avg_time_on_page$i, :day$i, :month$i, :year$i, :hour$i)";
  $i++;
}
$i=0;
$q=$db_handler->prepare($sql);
foreach ($all_data_rows as $data) {
  foreach ($data as $k => $v) {
    $q->bindValue(":$k$i", $v);
  }
  $i++;
}
$q->execute();
```

- Use a temporary table to avoid locking and disk overhead

First create a temporary table of type `HEAP` with the same structure as your target table, then insert into it: This will be much faster, as no locking and disk IO happens. Then run

```
INSERT INTO final_table SELECT * FROM temporary_table
```

If mitigation doesn't suffice, you will need to consider using non-parameterized queries for this use case. The usual caveats apply.